# Where am I going wrong with this variable?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I'm getting an Undefined variable: key for this

```
  $key .= $keys[mt_rand(0, count($keys) - 1)];
```

Comment: `count` accepts array or `countable` object, use `strlen` for strings.

Comment: If that's the exact message you're seeing then it's because you're attempting to append a value to `$key` which doesn't already exist.

Comment: *"I'm getting an Undefined variable: key"* - I hope you meant *"I'm getting an Undefined variable: **keys**"* - Otherwise, what you posted doesn't support the question/error.

Comment: @chris85 OP posted one line of code and we don't know where `$keys` is used and if there's more code before it and/or after it. Up until that person can post more code to show relevance, I feel the dupe is a valid close or if you can give me another duplicate for this, I'll add on to it. Your answer is very well-explained btw, I just want everyone to get to the bottom of this. A similar situation happened before where the OP didn't post what was needed, and it turned out that the duplicate I had for it, was valid. I just don't you/me/others to fall in the same trap.

Comment: @Kaorix is that the only line of code you have? If there is more, you will need to edit your question and add it. You need to respond.

Comment: @chris85 This answer in the duplicate seems to cover it http://stackoverflow.com/a/34354209/1415724 and if not, it could be edited in order to cover it and add an additional explanation, or add another community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` of the `.=` is trying to append to a previously existing `$key`, which you must not have (for example first iteration of a loop). Initialize `$key` as NULL or empty at the start of your script.

```
$key = '';
```

Comment: what's wrong with this https://eval.in/794558?

Comment: @KrisRoofe Use a generator with error reporting enabled, https://3v4l.org/SIXbB.

Comment: without initializing, works well. This will not lead to SO's issue.

Comment: @KrisRoofe No, it doesn't see link. The `.` is trying too append to a non-existent variable.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I check it on my centos command.